# How am I supposed to beat Chernabog?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

I am playing on Normal mode, Level 47-ish, and using the Colosseum key blade (the most powerful one I know of anyway). I am trying to beat Chernabog (when you revisit him, and he's in a volcano).

What I do is cast my protection spell, and then just start fighting him. I try my best to avoid his two main attacks (especially the one where he makes the volcano erupt), and his fire breath. However once I get him down to his second to last health bar then I start getting in trouble. Donald, and Goofie by this point are both incapacitated (until they get back up with their spell), but soon after get incapacitated. So really three is no point in healing them up aside from heals, and protection spells. Admittedly Donald is bit under leveled, because I neglected to play with him more in the early game so he is a tad bit weaker than Goofie.

Anyway am I just under leveled, or is there some trick I am missing here?

Comment: That almost sounds like you're talking about [Chernabog](http://www.khwiki.com/Chernabog)? Is that the volcano fight you mean? Or do you mean on Destiny Island when it splits?

Comment: Oh shoot. Chernabog it is. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be more than fine at that level for a decently normal difficulty fight with the right strategy. The key is to stay behind him and hit him on the back of his head. That will keep you out of the way of a lot of his attacks (though clearly not all). From there, it is just paying attention to when he starts the animations for the other moves.

The most important one to avoid is big fire explosion. For that one, he will lean forward and he starts to surround himself in small flames just before the big eruption. That one will do a lot of damage to you, so watch out for it.

Another one to avoid is the spinning glowy balls. For that one you should just be able to fly around away from them and outrun them. It is a bit tricky, but can be done.

Finally, if you're still having trouble, there is a little work-around you can use to make things a bit easier. You can actually land on the summit of the mountain (the fiery part, but it gives no damage) which will allow you to cast Tinkerbell. And Tinkerbell, if you were unaware, is the best summon in the game. Especially for boss fights. She will keep you very well healed and save you in times of need. You can also sometimes land on Chernabog's shoulder too, which will also allow you to cast it, but that is tougher.

And Aeroga can help protect from some of the damage if you're having trouble avoiding things.

Comment: I know Tink is probably the best summoner in the game by far (well again, as far as I'm aware). I didn't know why it wouldn't let me summon her, or any other summoner. Is that by design, or is just consequential? Either way having Tink will make life a whole lot easier.

Comment: @Scootaloo it is because the fight is in the air. You can't summon things while flying. So if you land, you will be able to summon her.

Comment: I understand that, but I was curious if they didn't want you to summoner anything for the fight. Obviously only the developers could confirm this, but it seems like they didn't want you to. Also you reminded me I need to unlock Aeroga (I think that is the Dalmatian unlock).